# Expand child div to to right side

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have a wordpress site/elementor and I want to extend a section/div to the right side outside the main div like in the picture below.

At the moment, the div has a fixed width of 1600px but the div goes beyond the page, which isn't really best practice and not really responsive.

A size of 100% covers only the main div.[image]

Does anyone have an idea as to how to fix this in css?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change fixed width 1600px to minWidth: 1600px
2. Or set `overflow: scroll` on a parent

Comment: i dont want any horizontal scrollbar on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `width: calc(100% + 30px);` on the child to achieve this.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Some text
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that 130% is too large, then you have the horizontal scrollbar...

Comment: Updated my snippet so now Im using calc(100% + 30px) instead

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow to hidden and then set the width beyond the main div.

```css
.someText{
  width: calc(100% + 5em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* To hide the horizontal scroll bar that may appear */
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution with calc.

```
.child{
width: calc((100vw - 1280px) / 2 + 1280px)
}
```

1280px is the parent div width.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Additionally, you can define a CSS variable (e.g. `--parent-div-width`) and reference it with `var(--parent-div-width)`, so it's better maintainable